# idapython - Get Xrefs to a stack variable

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, disassemblers, idapro-sdk

I am trying to write an IDAPython script that will return a list of references to a local stack-frame variable. However, I couldn't find any API that does so.

What I am trying to achieve is a code like:
`xrefs = get_variable_references('arg_4')` that will return the results corresponding with the GUI's results:

[image: GUI's results]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one function that does this: `build_stkvar_xrefs`, defined in C++ but exposed via the Python SWIG bindings. IDA builds stack xrefs dynamically when you ask for it. In order to use the function, it requires a little bit of setup.

You'll need to use a few functions to get what you need:

- `get_func(ea)`: retrieves the `func_t` structure for the function at `ea`
- `get_frame(func_t foo)`: returns the `struct_t` structure for the
  function frame specified by `foo`
- `DecodeInstruction(ea)`: returns the `inst_t` representing instruction at `ea`
- `get_stkvar(op_t op, sval_t v)`: `op` is a reference to an instruction, `v` is the immediate value in the operand. Usually you just use `op.addr`. It returns a tuple, `(member_t, val)`. `member_t` is a pointer to the stack variable, which is what we need. `val` is the same value as the `soff` field in the `member_t` for the stack var. More on this later.
- `xreflist_t()`: creates a new `xreflist` of `xreflist_entry_t`
- `build_stkvar_xrefs(xreflist_t xrefs, func_t func, member_t member)`: fills xrefs with `xreflist_entry_t`'s that represent the stack var xrefs given by `member` in `func`.
- `struct_t.get_member(x)`: You can use this method to iterate all stack variables in a frame to retrieve all `member_t`'s. If you want to build xrefs for all stack variables, this is usually easier.

Here's an example of how this all ties together:

```
# 0x4012d0 is the function address
# 0x4012dc is an instruction address referencing
# a stack variable. It looks like:
# mov [ebp - 4], ecx

pFunc = get_func(0x4012d0)
pFrame = get_frame(pFunc)
inst = DecodeInstruction(0x4012dc)
op = inst[0] #first operand references stack var
pMember, val = get_stkvar(op, op.addr)
xrefs = xreflist_t()
build_stkvar_xrefs(xrefs, pFunc, pMember)
for xref in xrefs:
    print hex(xref.ea) #print xref address

# Contrived member dictionary example.
dictMem = dict()
x = 0
while(x < pFrame.memqty):
    dictMem[GetMemberName(pFrame.id, pFrame.get_member(x).soff)] = pFrame.get_member(x)
    x = x+1
# given var name you can now use the
# dictionary to grab the member_t to pass
# to build_stkvar_xrefs
pMem = dictMem["var_4"]
xrefs = xreflist_t()
build_stkvar_xrefs(xrefs, pFunc, pMem)
for xref in xrefs:
    print hex(xref.ea) #print xrefs to var_4
```

`soff` isn't a stack offset. I think it means "structure offset", and it's an offset into the frame structure so you can retrieve other bits of information. You'll need this field to use other stack variable related functions such as: SetMemberType, SetMemberName, GetMemberName, DelStrucMember, etc.

So, for a simple on the fly variable name to xref lookup, you can do something like:

```
def get_stack_xrefs(func_ea, var_name):
    pFunc = get_func(func_ea)
    pFrame = get_frame(pFunc)
    pMember = None
    result = []
    while(x < pFrame.memqty):
        if GetMemberName(pFrame.id, pFrame.get_member(x).soff) == var_name:
           pMember = pFrame.get_member(x)
           break; 
        x = x+1
    if pMember: 
        xrefs = xreflist_t()
        build_stkvar_xrefs(xrefs, pFunc, pMember)
        for each in xrefs:
            result.append(each.ea)
    return result
```

If you want more information on these functions, I recommend taking a look at the following modules from the IDA SDK documentation (in no particular order):

- funcs.hpp
- frame.hpp
- struct.hpp

Reference: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/files.html

Answer (score 6):

*TL;DR: There's no simple API to achieve this, code is at the end of the answer or [here](https://gist.github.com/nirizr/fe0ce9948b3db05555da42bbfe0e5a1e).*

As far as I know, there is no easy way to get the references to stack structure. It seems like calling `idautils.XrefsTo(sid)` where `sid` is the frame id (retrieved using `idc.GetFrame`) should work, however I couldn't get it to yield any result in my attempts.

Instead, however, you could walk over the function's instructions and calculate the offsets into the stack manually whenever a stack reference operand is encountered.

I created a [gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/nirizr/fe0ce9948b3db05555da42bbfe0e5a1e) to show just that, and although I think it's quite self-explanatory I'll go over it briefly here.

First, we'll need a mapping of stack offsets to arguments, this is taken care of by the `find_stack_members` function, which uses the `idc.GetFrame` API function mentioned above to get the structure ID for the stack of a specific function. Then, it uses `idautils.StructMembers` API to iterate over the stack variables.

One interesting piece of logic in the `find_stack_members` function is that it uses the `<space>r` member name as the base of the stack (where the stack is once the function is entered), this is used later in `find_stack_xrefs` to calculate the stack offset of a variable based on the current stack delta and the operand immediate value.

The `find_stack_xrefs` function iterates over the instructions in the given function, and skips any instruction but those with a operand defined to reference the stack (note that arguments that reference the stack but aren't defined as such by either IDA's auto-analysis or manually will not be treated and hence will not count as a cross-reference).

If a stack offset operand exists in the instrcution, the `find_stack_xrefs` function will proceed to calculate it's offset using the stack's base offset (previously retrieved by `find_stack_members`), the current stack delta (calculated by IDA and available using the API `idc.GetSpd`) and the immediate taken from the Operand structure.

For convenience, I'm also including the code here:

```
import idc, idaapi, idautils, ida_xref

def find_stack_members(func_ea):
    members = {}
    base = None
    frame = idc.GetFrame(func_ea)
    for frame_member in idautils.StructMembers(frame):
        member_offset, member_name, _ = frame_member
        members[member_offset] = member_name
        if member_name == ' r':
            base = member_offset
    if not base:
        raise ValueError("Failed identifying the stack's base address using the return address hidden stack member")
    return members, base

def find_stack_xrefs(func_offset):
    func_ea = ida_funcs.get_func(func_offset).startEA
    members, stack_base = find_stack_members(func_ea)
    for func_item in FuncItems(func_ea):
        flags = idc.GetFlags(ea)
        stkvar = 0 if idc.isStkvar0(flags) else 1 if idc.isStkvar1(flags) else None
        if not stkvar:
            continue
        ida_ua.decode_insn(func_item)
        op = ida_ua.cmd.Operands[stkvar]
        stack_offset = op.addr + idc.GetSpd(func_item) + stack_base
        member = members[stack_offset]
        print("At offset {:x} stack member {} is referenced by operand number {}".format(func_item, member, stkvar))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_stack_xrefs(idc.ScreenEA())
```

Comment: This code doesn't work: it's outdated, it has multiple bugs and the algorithm is simply wrong. Don't anyone use it. I'll give you just a few examples: `flags = idc.GetFlags(ea)` is just wrong, there is no `ea` variable in this script. Meaning this code never actually worked. The `idc.GetSpd(func_item)` call is again wrong: `GetSpd` takes past-the-end address, not the address of the current instruction.

Comment: And even after you supply a proper argument for `GetSpd`, the formula `op.addr + idc.GetSpd(func_item) + stack_base` is still wrong. The `GetSpd` gets the difference between the initial and current values of ESP and doesn't help to determine which stack variable is referenced and on what offset. For example, I have instruction `mov     [rbp+0F0h+var_18], rax` at address `0x14001242A`. `var_18` is at offset 0x18 respectively. The past-the-end address is `0x140012431`, so I do idc.GetSpd(0x140012431), and get `-0x118`.

Comment: Then formula: `op.addr + idc.GetSpd(func_item) + stack_base` turns into: `0x14001242A + (-0x118) + 0x118`, which equals to `0x14001242A`, which is the instruction address, not the stack offset. Which makes this answer completely wrong. If you want a working solution, check out the accepted answer by @mayahustle.

Comment: @KulaGGin Thanks for catching my errors! It's been a while and I'm not sure I tested the code. It was meant as a thought process snippet more than as a working solution. Thanks for pointing it out!