# idapython：How can I get xref to a stack variable in the form of pseudocode

Tags: idapython

I have learned about how to get xref to a stack variable,but it is in the form of 
assembly:[idapython - Get Xrefs to a stack variable](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16055/idapython-get-xrefs-to-a-stack-variable)

This way works well on a variable like [ebp+var_0] but do not support the registers.Some times if  a segment error occurs on an instruction like "mov eax,[esi]", I have to know where the value of "esi" comes from,so I need to make sure I can get xref to a register.

It also means I have to do more work about analysis even if ida has provided.
I think the xref in the form of pseudocode is more clear and convenient, just like what i am used to look up in ida:
[image]

ida define the stack data and registers to variables like "v1" or "v13",and then I can get xref by press 'X'.
I have searched for some time,including the examples in github.There are some ways to get xref to the global variables but not the stack variables.So if there exist any API about this?

Comment: Or I have to take a fool way——get the function's pseudocode in form of strings,and then use some string manipulation to find out the xref to a variable